# Mosaic - Background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mosaic

I want to make a mosaic background (that mean a wall of pictures) for my website.

The picture are all with the same size and retrieve randomly from the database and limit at 10.

I'm using bootstrap.

It should be responsive.

What are the proper way to do that ? (Multiple div with background image property, ...)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxY4P.png)

Thank's,

Answer (score 0):

What's your describing looks like a Masonry design. You can do that with plain CSS thanks to the "column-count" property. Have a look at http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: Thank's for your answer ! I didn't know that property  i will take a look.